# Error when building iOS app of react native project

Tags: xcode, react-native, build-error

I created my first react native app using the guide from the react native website.

After running the following command:

```
 npx react-native run-ios
```

I got the following error:

```
The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-eddynynsuvavhfgrpdccjaqaaqym/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-rncore.build/Script-46EB2E00018190.sh (in target 'React-rncore' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

I tried changing the permissions of the file and adding sudo in front of the `npx react-native run-ios`, but could not fix the issue.

I tried opening the Xcode project file `/ios` and building it through Xcode. But it gave the following error:

```
/Users/kanishkawithanawasam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-bofqwnifbnfeyzeyzmjkvmdaapoe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/AwesomeProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject.build/DerivedSources/AwesomeProject_vers.c module map file '/Users/kanishkawithanawasam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-bofqwnifbnfeyzeyzmjkvmdaapoe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap' not found
```

At the same time, a terminal opens and the terminal is frozen at the following line:

```
 ➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-RCTActionSheet' in project 'Pods'
    ➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-RCTAnimation' in project 'Pods'
    ➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-RCTAppDelegate' in project 'Pods'
    ➜ Explicit dependency on target 'React-RCTBlob' in the project
```

I have to enter command+c to terminate the process. Please help me to fix this!
thank you!

Computer:  MacBook Pro M2